# Prove that Newtons Method works for a concrete polynomial

Tags: newton-raphson

Can somebody help me with following:
Let $f(x)=x^5-x+1$ and let $x$ be the limit of the Newton series $x_n=x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$.
How do I prove that $x$ is a root of $f$, i.e. $f(x)=0$.

I have tried to proove that $|f(x_N)|<\frac{1}{n}$ for some $N$ big enough, by using the triangle inequality, but without succes.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Assume that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=x \in \Bbb R$$

$ f $ and its derivative  $ f' $ are continuous at $ \Bbb R $.

So

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{n-1}=x$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x_{n-1})=f(x)$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f'(x_{n-1})=f'(x)$$

and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=x=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

By MVT, it is easy to check that the root of $ f(x)=0 $ is in $ [-2,-1]$, so $ f'(x)\ne 0$.